# Does an object appear darker as the distance to the observer increases?

Tags: visible-light, geometric-optics

If light from a surface is reflected in a cylindrical matter (like not a perfect straight beam), would the object appear darker at a great distance because the rays of light stray away further away from each other and therefore lower the luminance?

I know this is not a very specific question, but I'm just asking myself right now and won't rest when a question really bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed! When light is diverging, its intensity goes down with increasing distance. This is the reason, for example, that the nearby sun is brighter than a faraway star!